# Is it possible to change the frequency of ticks on a pyplot INDEPENDENT of length of data set and zoom?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot data using matplotlib I always have 5-9 ticks on my x-axis independent of the range I plot, and if I zoom on the x-axis the tick spacing decreases, so I still see 5-9 ticks.

however, I would like 20-30 ticks on my x-axis!

I can achieve this with the following:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50] 
y = [1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 5] 

number_of_ticks_on_x_axis = 20

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, (max(x) - min(x))/number_of_ticks_on_x_axis))

plt.show()
```

If I now zoom on the x-axis, no new ticks appear between the existing ones. I would like to still have ~20 ticks however much I zoom.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to fix the no. of ticks on the *X* axis

```
...
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(15, min_n_ticks=15))
...
```

Please look at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator) for `MaxNLocator`

---

#### Example

```
In [36]: import numpy as np 
    ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                  
In [37]: from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator                                        
In [38]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))                                           
In [39]: ax.grid()                                                                        
In [40]: ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(min_n_ticks=15))                          
In [41]: x = np.linspace(0, 1, 51)                                                        
In [42]: y = x*(1-x)                                                                      
In [43]: plt.plot(x, y)                                                                   
Out[43]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f9eab409e10>]
```

gives

[image]

and when I zoom into the maximum of the curve I get

[image]

Comment: This is a really elegant solution.

Comment: However, I think I'm actually looking for nbins

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=20))

Comment: I haven't played long enough with `MaxNLocator` to advise you on the best selection of parameters in your particular usage, but definitely I think that `MaxNLocator` is what you need...

Answer (score 0):

You can link a callback function to an event in the canvas.  In you case you can trigger a function that updates the axis when a redraw occurs.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50] 
y = [1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 5] 

n = 20

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, (max(x) - min(x))/n), rotation=90)

def on_zoom(event):
    ax = plt.gca()
    fig = plt.gcf()
    x_min, x_max = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(x_min, x_max, n))
    # had to add flush_events to get the ticks to redraw on the last update.
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_zoom)
```